# Defining an abstract type in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to have the array subscript before the variable name in declaration?

For example, is it possible to have

```
char [10]data;
```

where the intended declaration is:

```
char data[10];
```

I know that this might be stretching it a bit too much, but I have the variable type defined using `#define`, which I need to change from int to char[10] type.

So, could I just use `#define TYPE char[10]` instead of `#define TYPE int`? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

**Edit**:

Must I use 2 different #define statements like this?

```
#define TYPE char
#define SIZE [10]
```

and then use:

```
TYPE data SIZE;
```

Comment: Is there a good reason you are trying to use `#define` for that instead of going the obvious normal and straightforward way with `typedef`?

Comment: abstract data types...need to only change the TYPE definition to use the code for another data type

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to consider using a typedef for this:

```
typedef char TYPE[10];
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `data` to be the name of his variable; maybe change it to `TYPE` here to match the question?

Comment: +1 Just to complement mipadi's answer ... and then define your object with `TYPE data;` meaning `data` is an array of 10 char.

Comment: ...and if you need it to be a macro, then `typedef char char10[10];` followed by `#define TYPE char10`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
typedef char TYPE[10];
```